# Images loading very slowly in Fancybox even though I am preloading all of them (FancyApps2)

Tags: image, fancybox-2, preload

I have a slide show with bet 20 - 40 images, but there is a significant delay before each image loads even though I've set them all to preload *(I recently increased it to preload: '40')*. What can I do to improve this?

The settings for the slideshow are:

```
$(function () {
$('.fancybox').fancybox({ 
  autoResize: true,
  autoCenter: true,
  scrolling: 'no',
  preload: '40',
     helpers: {         
            overlay: {
                closeClick: false
                },
            },                            
        });
```

I'm using it in conjunction with this function:

```
function manipulateDOM1() {
    changeObjectsTrendy();
    NextImageTrendy();
}
function changeObjectsTrendy() {
    document.getElementById("questionTrendy").innerHTML = textTrendy[textTrendyNumber];
}
function NextImageTrendy() {
    if (imgTrendyNumber < NumberOfTrendyImages)
    {
    imgTrendyNumber++;
    document.images["trendy"].src = trendy[imgTrendyNumber];
    document.images["trendyControl"].src = trendyControl[imgTrendyNumber];
    textTrendyNumber++;
    document.getElementById["questionTrendy"].innerHTML = textTrendy[textTrendyNumber];
}
```

Comment: have you tried `preload: 40` .... normally Boolean and integer values go without quotes. Also, you don't need the trial comma if there is not a following option. You'll see IE complaining

Comment: Good to know :-D I just saw that there was a recent update to the js for the slideshow, and thankfully that made a huge difference (there's now only a marginal delay) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved :-D

I just saw that there had been a recent update to the js for the fancybox slideshow, and thankfully that's made a huge difference (there's now only a marginal delay) :-)